# Fade out parallax layer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a fade out effect on a parallax layer and I've done this:

```
if(currentBackgroundPhase == BackgroundPhase.Night)
{
    foreach(SpriteRenderer sprite in GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
    {
        if (sprite.name.Contains("Cloud"))
        {
            sprite.color = new Color(opaqueCloud.r, opaqueCloud.g, opaqueCloud.b, transitionTimeElapsed / TRANSITION_TIME);
        }
    }
}
```

The parallax keeps repositioning cloud sprites and this is the only way I can think to do this.
I've looked profiler and didn't see a drop on performance when the if is called.
Is this too expensive / unefficient because the GetComponensInChildren? If so, is there other way to do this?

I looked on profiler's scripts graphic to see if this is too much but didn't notice anything strange.

I can't test on a bad device because I don't have one, and I want this to work on every android device...

The maximum amount of spriterenderers that can be in children is 20 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some tips that could be helpful to you

1. Use object pooling if needed as you don't have to destroy and instantiate clouds again and again.
2. Try Avoiding Foreach loop its not noticeable right now but it does have an impact over for loop.

If a for each loop used for collection or array of object (i.e. array of all elements other than primitive datatype), GC (Garbage Collector) is called to free space of reference variable at the end of a for each loop.

```
foreach (Gameobject obj in Collection)
{
    //Code Do Task
}
```

Whereas for loop is used to iterate over the elements using an index and so primitive datatype will not affect performance compared to a non-primitive datatype.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Collection.length; i++){
    //Get reference using index i;
    //Code Do Task
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the foreach advice, I will refactor the foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pooling Gameobjects. Just activating deactivating them.

If one cloud is 100% transparent you can deactivate it and reuse somewhere else. If you are moving the clouds it should be possible.

Comment: They are shown in the screen all time (it's the background) so that's not an option.

Comment: Well if one cloud is 100% transparent you can deactivate it and reuse somewhere else or did i understand it wrong. If you are moving the clouds it should be possible.

Comment: The problem is that they are transparent for only 1 frame, they are like a ghost most of the time, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Well try pooling if you are generating and destroying. Reuse your clouds don't destroy them

Comment: Since the parallax script was an external asset, I didn't know that the elements were reused, but I looked in depth now and it reuses it repositioning the images. Question updated.

Comment: Do you call your function inside update ? Try to assign it once in start so you call get component just a few times not on every frame. Create an array with components and fill it on start. After that just iterate throw your array.